# No se guardan los valores de un ChoiceField en la base de datos (django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy mostrando un formulario que cuenta con un campo de selección entre 2 opciones, este se muestra bien y aparentemente cumple su función, solo que no guarda en la base de datos el valor seleccionado. Estoy usando un modelo User personalizado para la gestión de usuarios en django 3.1.2. Dentro del administrador de django y en el template para editar la información del usuario si se puede cambiar el valor del campo modalidad y si lo guarda correctamente, pero lo ideal es que se guarde ese valor desde un inicio.

`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    MODALIDAD_CHOICES = (
        ('Asesor', 'Asesor'),
        ('Promotor', 'Promotor'),
    )

    # Campos obligatoríos (Asesores)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nombre(s)')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Apellidos')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    modalidad = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=MODALIDAD_CHOICES,
        null=False,
        blank=False
        )
    asesor = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    # Campos no obligatoríos (Promotores)
    bienvenida_txt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    despedida_txt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img/promotores')
    url = models.TextField(blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'telefono']
    objects = UserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile_pic = str(self.foto).replace(' ', '_').lower()
        self.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?first_name={}&last_name={}&profile_pic={}&bienbenida={}&despedida={}'.format(
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
            profile_pic,
            self.bienvenida_txt,
            self.despedida_txt
        )

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
        
    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

`managers.py`

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager, models.Manager):
    
    def _create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, telefono, password, is_staff, is_superuser, is_active, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            username=username,
            email=email,
            telefono=telefono,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            is_active=is_active,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, telefono, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(first_name, last_name, username, email, telefono, password, False, False, True, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, telefono, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(first_name, last_name, username, email, telefono, password, True, True, True, **extra_fields)
```

`forms.py`

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Contraseña',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
        )
    )
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirmar Contraseña',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
        )
    )


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'username',
            'email',
            'telefono',
            'modalidad',
            'asesor',
            'bienvenida_txt',
            'despedida_txt',
            'foto',
            'url',
        )

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'telefono': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'modalidad': forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'modalidad', 'class': 'form-control promotor-field'}),
            'asesor': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control promotor-field'}),
            'bienvenida_txt': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control promotor-field'}),
            'despedida_txt': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control promotor-field'}),
            'foto': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control promotor-field'}),
            'url': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control promotor-field'}),
        }

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']:
            self.add_error('confirm_password', 'Las contraseñas no coinsiden')
```

`views.py`

```
class UserRegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/users/register.html'
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:u-dashboard')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:u-login')

    def form_valid(self, form): 
        User.objects.create_user(
            form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            form.cleaned_data['username'],
            form.cleaned_data['email'],
            form.cleaned_data['telefono'],
            form.cleaned_data['modalidad'],
            asesor=self.request.user.username,
            bienvenida_txt=form.cleaned_data['bienvenida_txt'],
            despedida_txt=form.cleaned_data['despedida_txt'],
            foto=form.cleaned_data['foto'],
            url=form.cleaned_data['url'],
        )

        print('-----MOOD HERE-----> ' + form.cleaned_data['modalidad'])

        return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

`form.cleaned_data['modalidad']` Si devuelve el valor seleccionado, pero simplemente no se guarda en la base de datos. Mas adelante en los templetes se necesita saber la modalidad del usuario ya que cada modalidad tiene acceso a diferente información del template. Además de mostrarse en listas separadas en sus respectivos templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer por alguna razón el campo no se asignaba automáticamente cuando se ejecutaba la función `create_user` del modelo `User`, así que intente asignarlo y guardarlo manualmente y funciono. De tal manera que mi `views.py` quedo asi:

```
class UserRegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/users/register.html'
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:u-dashboard')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:u-login')

def form_valid(self, form): 
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
        form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
        form.cleaned_data['username'],
        form.cleaned_data['email'],
        form.cleaned_data['telefono'],
        form.cleaned_data['modalidad'],
        asesor=self.request.user.username,
        bienvenida_txt=form.cleaned_data['bienvenida_txt'],
        despedida_txt=form.cleaned_data['despedida_txt'],
        foto=form.cleaned_data['foto'],
        url=form.cleaned_data['url'],
    )
    user.modalidad = form.cleaned_data['modalidad']
    user.save()

    return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```